# How to show a column value horozontaly in crystal reports?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

How to show a column value horozontaly in crystal reports :

```
 Itemid PurchaseDate        itemid Purchasedate   itemid Purchasedate  

 1200   10/11/2013          1204  11/11/2013      1205 12/11/2013       
 1206   13/11/2103
```

Thanks:

Comment: Please if some one can help... i am printing vertically eaisly but stuck on it when it comes to print horizontaly..

currently i am printing like this:

Itemid Purchasedate

1200    10/11/2013

1204    11/11/2013

1205     12/11/2013

Answer (score 0):

How many columns do you want to display? 
As this is also a concern, Report will keep on expanding then.
I think this link can some what help you.

[Printing data horizontally](http://vinodkotiya.blogspot.in/2011/09/crystal-report-show-data-horizontally.html)

[Print horizontally](http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=19004)

Comment: i Have only 3 columns to display.. and i am trying these solution. and let you know, worked or not.